# Bad contentType for search handler :text/xml; charset=UTF-8

Tags: magento-1.9, error, extensions, solr

Anyone know about this error? I get it while indexing.

```
Error reindexing Solr: Ping query caused exception: Bad contentType for search handler :text/xml; charset=UTF-8 request={q={!lucene}*:*&timeAllowed=5&json.nl=flat&omitHeader=true&wt=json&echoParams=all&distrib=false}
```

I think it's referring to this:

```
if (!isset($options['headers']['Content-Type'])) {
    $options['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8';
}
```

Also believe it has something to do with a newer version of Solr.

If I comment the above line out I get a new error:

```
Error reindexing Solr: missing content stream
```